# grouping values of a dataframe with string

Tags: python, string, pandas

The following code works for classifying a single message

```
total_frame['dummy_message'][total_frame['Message'].str.contains(['rrc'],case = False)] = 'msg1'
```

```
index  Message

0       rrc
1       as1
2       as1
3        a2
4       as1
5       a2
```

However if I want to classify all the messages in a message column, I want to use something like this

```
total_frame['dummy_message'[total_frame['Message'].str.contains(['rrc','as1','as2','a2'],case = False)] = 'msg1','msg2','msg3','msg4'
```

This doesn't work as str.contains doesnt accept a list.
The output should look something like this

```
index  Message dummy message

0       rrc          msg1
1       as1          msg2
2       as1          msg2
3        a2          msg4
4       as2          msg3
5       a2           msg4
```

Is there any alternative?

Comment: Can you please provide a [MCVE] ?

Comment: I'd assume the filter function can help. Not enough context.

Comment: The assumption here is that you're using `str.contains` because these terms are present as substrings, right?

Comment: yup but just for example purpose i used the substrings(rather than whole string) as elements of the column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialise a mapping of substrings to categories, then use [**`str.extract`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to extract, and [**`map`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to classify them:

```
mapping = dict(zip(
    ['rrc', 'as1', 'as2', 'a2'], 
    ['msg1', 'msg2', 'msg3', 'msg4']))

df['category'] = (
    df['Message'].str.extract(r'(?i)({})'.format('|'.join(mapping)), expand=False)
                 .map(mapping))
```

If case-insensitivity is important, modify your regex as: `r'(?i)({})'.format('|'.join(mapping))`.

**Minimal Code Example**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Message': ['this is as1', 'abcd rrc', 'xyz as2']})
df

       Message
0  this is as1
1     abcd rrc
2      xyz as2

df['category'] = (
    df['Message'].str.extract(r'({})'.format('|'.join(mapping)), expand=False)
                 .map(mapping))
df

       Message category
0  this is as1     msg2
1     abcd rrc     msg1
2      xyz as2     msg3
```